# Bidirectinal contacts sync

Tags: android, synchronization, contacts, bidirectional

What is the best approach to develop an android application which will find another phone on the same WiFi network and sync the contacts bidirectionally without the use of any Cloud service?

Comment: what you tried so far?

Comment: I am using RMI to transfer JSON from one phone to another. I am still confused about the bidirectional approach.